# French hyphenation in printed books and publications

Tags: typographie, trait-d-union

When printing books and articles in French, can the last word in a paragraph be hyphenated if part of the word is on a separate line by itself?

In French books, can the last word on a recto (right-hand side with odd page numbers) be hyphenated and carried over to the next verso page?

Can proper names for people and places be hyphenated in printed French texts?

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell (cf. [Stan Deville's design guide](http://www.keskispass.devilles.ca/2016/03/regles-de-mise-en-page-typographique/), [Valérie Fourneaux's rules of typography](http://www.actionasbl.net/site/valerie/Files/Other/Publisher%202013/04%20-%20Quelques%20regles%20typographiques.pdf)), [orphans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans) are also undesirable in French typography, so ideally, the final word of a paragraph would never be hyphenated.

However, the other scenarios that you mentioned appear to be acceptable, and they show up in some of my recent reading. For example, my 1964 copy of « Les faux-monnayeurs » shows at least one instance where a word is hyphenated on a recto page and carried over to a verso page.

[image: Les faux-monnayeurs]

There is also an instance of name that is hyphenated and broken up into two lines.

[image: Les faux-monnayeurs]